# Cannot attach a Service Role Policy to a Customer Role

Tags: amazon-web-services, roles

I have a problem when creating a Role I am getting an error that says “Cannot attach a Service Role Policy to a Customer Role”

Comment: This isn't a pure aws error as there is no such thing as a "customer role" in aws. If you are using some third party software, tag your question with it. And put more detail about how you're creating it, what settings, etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, there is something called Customer Managed Role, which the above error seems to display as 'Customer Role'.

From AWS documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_terms-and-concepts.html#iam-term-service-role)

> A role that a service assumes to perform actions in your account on your behalf. When you set up some AWS service environments, you must define a role for the service to assume. This service role must include all the permissions required for the service to access the AWS resources that it needs.

Now if you create a role, which isn't a service role, and attach permissions yourself, it appears under what AWS shows as Customer Managed Role (Screenshot below). If you look carefully, the service roles in AWS show the AWS box icon and the Customer Managed ones don't.

**Reason:** I was facing the above error as well and the reason was that my Role had custom inlined policies attached. If a Role has custom attached policies (inlined), AWS doesn't let you attach the Service Roles to it. You can filter the roles and find out what's causing the issue.

[image]

I hope this is documented somewhere as I was scratching my head for quite some time on this.

Comment: Yes we can say policy has 4 types 
- Customer managed 
- Customer Inline
- AWS managed
- AWS managed - job function